# C++: Pass with "typedef" defined class as parameter

Tags: c++, object, boost, instance, typedef

I am creating an instance Dataset::Ptr data and then I need to pass this instance to another method, but I am having trouble with passing "data" as an argument.

The Dataset class is defined as follows:

```
//Definition of "Dataset" class in Datset.h
class Dataset : public Objects
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Dataset> Ptr;

...

        void foo();
```

In the class where I instanciate a "Dataset" object I have:

```
void doWork(Dataset::Ptr* ds)
{
ds->foo();------>Here I get the error that foo is not defined. ds doesnt have any 
}

void Function(){
Dataset::Ptr* ds;
....do something with ds....
doWork(&ds);
}
```

The error is that boost::shared_ptr cannot be changed into Dataset::Ptr.

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass the instance properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dataset::Ptr` is a pointer already, `Dataset::Ptr*` means `boost::shared_ptr<Dataset>* Ptr`;
**`ds` becomes a pointer `to boost::shared_ptr`** which has no `foo()` function defined.

update

```
void doWork(Dataset::Ptr* ds)
```

to

```
void doWork(Dataset::Ptr ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dataset::Ptr*` means pointer to `boost::shared_ptr<Dataset>`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `doWork` takes a pointer to a (shared) pointer. So `ds->foo()` tries to call a `foo` member of the shared pointer, not the object that points to.

You probably want to pass the shared pointer by value or `const` reference:

```
void doWork(Dataset::Ptr ds);
doWork(ds);
```

But if your pointer dance is necessary for some reason, then you'll need to dereference twice:

```
(*ds)->foo();
```